# JQuery Sortable and Draggable - Moving both horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a set of elements on screen arranged in a grid form(say a 3x3 matrix).

`<div>Part_1_1           Part_1_2              Part_1_3</div>`

`<div>Part_2_1           Part_2_2              Part_2_3</div>`

`<div>Part_3_1           Part_3_2              Part_3_3</div>`

I need to be able to move each row/column as is both vertically and horizontally and I should not be able to move individual elements.
Each row is enclosed in a div(in turn each part is contained in its own div container). As a result of which I'm able to move each row vertically.

In addition to this I also need to move each column horizontally. I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try to apply the sorting on the row level and then update the rest of the rows on a callback.

You can also style it to have the appearance of a vertical row.

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="col1">11</span><span class="col2">12</span><span class="col3">13</span></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="col1">21</span><span class="col2">22</span><span class="col3">23</span></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="col1">31</span><span class="col2">32</span><span class="col3">33</span></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#sortable li").sortable({
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var index = ui.item.index();
        $("."+$(ui.item).attr("class")).each(function(){
            if(this!=ui.item[0]){
              var list = $(this).closest("li");
              $(this).detach()
              if($(list.children().get(index)).length>0)
                  $(list.children().get(index)).before(this);
              else
                  $(list).append(this); 
            }
        })
    }
});
```

I add the fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/536/